# Update the csv display_names to column_names based on Query

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which consists of following.

```
x1,x2,x3
66,1000,Copper
```

Here, the x1,x2,x3 are the display names.

My major goal is to update the table based on csv columns and values using

```
pd.read_csv()
df.to_sql("table", engine)
```

In my case, I get **display_names** instead of **column_names**

I need to edit the csv display names to column names first, based on display names.

I need to take each display_name from csv and using below query I need to replace the column_name in csv.

```
select column_name from table2 where display_name ='x1'
```

so i need to replace the display name with column name using the above query for all display names and get as below.

```
        x_1,x_2,x_3
        66,1000,Copper
```

And i'll use **read_csv** and **to_sql** to update the table.

I need to understand how can I iterate with the query display names from csv and replace the display with column_values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps select the column display name mappings first into a dictionary and then replace in the `df` before `df.to_sql` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

eg

```
df.rename(columns={"x1": "x_2", "x2": "x_2"})
```

Comment: there are total 30 columns. Is there any other way in pandas ?

Comment: shouldn't matter, get your dict from `res = session.execute("select display_name, column_name from table2")` `col_map = {display_name: column_name for display_name, column_name in res.all()`